# How to enable different fields for different users with the same profile and record type in Salesforce

Tags: permissions, fields

I have a profile XYZ in salesforce which has access to fields A,B,C and D.  I have 2 users, User A and User B. User A needs access to fields A,B,C only while user B needs access to fields A,B,C and D.
Is there a way to achieve this without creating new profiles or record types or page layouts ?

Comment: Welcome to SFSE.  Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour].  Have you looked at Permission Sets?  See Salesforce Trailhead for tutorials on profiles and permission sets.

Answer (score 0):

You can use permission sets to grant additional access.

Have profile have access to fields A,B,C.
Create a new permset which has access to field D and grant this to user B.